# Why do I get bash integer expression error from [ ${guess[0]} -eq num ]?

Tags: bash

I am trying to prompt the user to guess a value between 0-9. I am getting the error integer expression expected. I don't understand why can someone explain where I am going wrong?

```
num=8

echo "Enter a value between 0-9"
read -a guess

if [ ${guess[0]} -eq num ] ; then
    echo "You guesses the right number"
elif [ ${guess[0]} -gt num ] ; then 
    echo "You guessed too high"
elif [ ${guess[0]} -lt num ] ; then
    echo "You guess too low"
fi
```

Comment: Paste your code at http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see what's wrong.

Comment: Try `${num[0]}` instead of `num` !

Comment: @F.Hauri: `num` is not an _array_; while `${num[0]}` will also work, `"$num"` is the right approach.

Comment: @mklement0 It was a joke, but if `${guess[0]}` work, also `${num[0]}` will work too!

Comment: @F.Hauri  `${:)[0]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make only the minimum number of changes necessary for this code to run correctly:

```
#!/bin/sh

num=8

echo "Enter a value between 0-9"
read guess

if [ "$guess" -eq "$num" ] ; then
    echo "You guesses the right number"
elif [ "$guess" -gt "$num" ] ; then 
    echo "You guessed too high"
elif [ "$guess" -lt "$num" ] ; then
    echo "You guess too low"
fi
```

Notes:

- Since you're reading only a single value, no compelling reason to use an array -- just as easy to take out the `-a` argument to `read`; doing this also makes your code compatible with POSIX sh, and thus with `#!/bin/sh` on all systems with POSIX-compliant shells.
- You need to expand your variables when using `test` (or `[`). `$num`, not bare `$num`; the latter is only possible in a numeric context, whereas `test` is a regular command as much as the parser is concerned -- it doesn't create any special context at a syntax level.
- Because `[` is a regular command, you need spaces after it, just like any other command name.
- Because `[` is a regular command, you need spaces before the `]` it expects as its last argument -- same as when passing arguments to anything else.
- If your shell were bash (your script started with `#!/bin/bash`), you could use a math context: `if (( guess == num ))`, or `if (( guess > num ))`. This **is** a math context, and has special parsing rules.

Comment: Yeah I made some errors posting but this works. I am still trying to learn bash. This works correctly. I will accept post